# Deploy midlet on Nokia mobile

Tags: deployment, java-me, nokia, midlet

I have written a midlet which asks username and password and connect to servlet running on tomcat to validate. When I run the midlet on the emulator provided by sun toolkit, first time it asks "This midlet wants to connect to http://... using airtime" and asks user permission. I want to know is there anyway to get rid of this? Once this app is installed on a real mobile would it ask user permission every time when application starts or it can be set at installation time?

Secondly how do I deploy my midlet jar on Nokia E65?

---

I used the Nokia software came along with the cellphone to deploy my application on handset. Whenever I start the application, first time it asks me "This midlet wants to connect to http://... using airtime"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad first: You need to setup proper security permissions for your midlet and secondly you will need to sign it with some kind of certificate the device trusts. This is easy for the emulator where you can create self-signed CA and import into the emulator key-store. For real devices you will probably need some commercial (paid) certificate.

Ad second: You will probably need to make the midlet JaD/Jar available via HTTP. Did you try uploading the jar/jad to the phone and "launching" it there. Nokia Application Manager which comes with Nokia PC Suite might be also a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign the application if you want to get rid of(to an extend) these kind permission issues. A signed application has more access to the device's resources such as camera ,network . Also the user can set the permission for the application ,such as "ask for first time", "ask every time ","Do not allow" etc...  You will get more of these options if the application is signed .

To deploy you can use the software that Nokia has given ,the PC suit. or you can use the OTA method where you upload your signed( or unsigned) jar and jad files to a webserver and download the it from there using the mobile browser. Just open the jad file from your mobile browser, it will verify the certificate and will down load and install the jar file.

First method will be good enough till you are having the ready to go application.